Inconsistent getCurrentPose() with TF2 pose information
I am getting robot pose information by using Moveit2 Script ( getCurrentPose() method). When I tried to verify the getCurrentPose information, I found that it was inconsistent with TF information.

ROS Distro: [|Humble|]

OS Version:Ubuntu 22.04

Binary build

Fast DDS
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/pose.hpp>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
// Initialize ROS
rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
// Declare Node
std::shared_ptrrclcpp::Node node =
std::make_sharedrclcpp::Node("get_current_pose",
rclcpp::NodeOptions().automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(
true));
// We spin up a SingleThreadedExecutor for the current state monitor to get
// information about the robot's state.
rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor executor;
executor.add_node(node);
std::thread spinner = std::thread(&executor { executor.spin(); });
// Create the MoveIt MoveGroup Interface
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group_interface =
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface(node, "ur_manipulator");
// print current pose
geometry_msgs::msg::Pose current_pose =
move_group_interface.getCurrentPose().pose;
// Print the current pose of the end effector
RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Current pose: X:%f Y:%f Z:%f x:%f y:%f z:%f w:%f",
current_pose.position.x,
current_pose.position.y,
current_pose.position.z,
current_pose.orientation.x,
current_pose.orientation.y,
current_pose.orientation.z,
current_pose.orientation.w);
// Shutdown ROS
rclcpp::shutdown();
spinner.join();
return 0;
}





Expected behaviour
TF Gui Output
tool0, wrist_3_link
Position: X: 0.382871 Y:0.351937 Z:0.808952
Orientation X:-0.70715 Y:0.0057097 Z: 0.00065606 W: 0.70709
Actual behaviour
Moveit2 Output
Current pose: pos.X:0.193414 pos.Y:0.286017 pos.Z:0.546773 ori.x:-0.707120 ori.y:0.000571 ori.z:0.000656 ori.w:0.707093
Why they are different from each other between Moveit2 Console and TF GUI ?
